# Parameter in actionListener

Tags: jsf, richfaces, actionlistener, ajax4jsf

I use JSF 1.2.How can I pass some parameters to actionListener which is called on the event specified in a4j:support for h:inputText?

```
<h:inputText id="dateToText" value="#{flowScope.fileSearchCriteria.toDateStr}">
    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="datePanel1"    
      actionListener="#fileSearchCriteria.changeTextToDate}"  />
    <a4j:actionparam name="strxxx"                                
      assignTo="#{flowScope.fileSearchCriteria.strxxx}" value="#{resourceBundle.searchIn}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is correct, but instead of actionListner, I would switch to action. I don't think there is guarantee that a4j:actionparam will be invoked before actionListener. But action will always be invoked last.